# Gradle not picking the mentioned version of elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, gradle, build.gradle, version

Though I specify the version of elastic search as 6.3.1 in build.gradle file, my
project is taking latest version of elastic search causing errors unless I  specify "applyplugin:'io.spring.dependency-management' " in build.gradle file. Is it mandatory to provide applyplugin to avoid this issue or is there any other way. Can anyone pls help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please help us and provide the build.gradle code that failing , the error log maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some other dependency that pulls in a later version of elasticsearch. You can investigate which one using the '[gradle dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html)' command or using the build scan. When found, you can [exclude the elasticsearch dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:excluding-transitive-deps) in the definition of the one that pulls it in.

Or you can [define a strict version](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:enforcing_dependency_version) of elasticsearch (but beware, this may cause other errors).